# How to store MongoDB Realm results in state witth Jetpack Compose?

Tags: mongodb, kotlin, realm, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

My goal is to store the results of a query on my Realm database in state, so that my View wil update automatically if the state gets updated.

I am struggling with how I should do this.

What I am currently doing (and I know this is wrong and does not work) is:

```
var todos by mutableStateOf<RealmResults<Todo>?>(null)
```

and then, later in my code, when fetching the todos:

```
database.where<Todo>().findAllAsync()
```

Android Studio even warns me with the message:

> Creating a MutableState object with a mutable collection type.

I know that what I am doing is wrong, but sadly when I use mutableStateListOf() instead of mutableStateOf(), it says:

> Type 'SnapshotStateList<RealmResults?>' has no method 'getValue(TodoViewModel, KProperty<*>)' and thus it cannot serve as a delegate

How can I store the results of my query using Jetpack Compose state?

Comment: with `mutableStateListOf` you don't need delegation, replace `var todos by` with `val todos =`

Comment: @PylypDukhov thanks for your comment. I changed it, but how do I make the correct query of the correct type now? 

'todos = database.where<Todo>().findAll()' fails now because required type is 'SnapshotStateList<RealmResults<Todo>?>' but the found type is '
RealmResults<Todo!>!'

Comment: @PylypDukhov I managed to get it working. I found out that `todos = database.where<Todo>().findAll().toMutableStateList()` would make the correct type BUT it does not update the state. 

I have no idea whether what I'm doing now is the correct way, but it works. What I do is: 
    `val todosResults = database.where<Todo>().findAll()
    todos.clear()

    for (todo in todosResults) {
    todos.add(todo)
    }`
It seems like this triggers the state to update.

Comment: `todos.clear(); todos.addAll(todosResults)`